# Powershell translated to Python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell-5.1

I am a newbie with Python, coming from an extensive C# and Powershell background.  I am having trouble with figuring out how to do the following in Python:

```
$bodyLines = ( 
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"insert`"$LF",
    "true$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"debug`"$LF",
    "true$LF",    
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"$path`"",
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
    $fileEnc,
    "--$boundary--$LF" 
) -join $LF
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?  You will have to explain what the desired output is to a python user before you can expect much of an answer.

Comment: Desired output: GUID boundary --e908345c-4304-45c3-9355-78b802bcbf0b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="insert"

true

--e908345c-4304-45c3-9355-78b802bcbf0b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="debug"

true

--e908345c-4304-45c3-9355-78b802bcbf0b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream